# Check for updates on a Server via SSH

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, updates, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
while read P
do
ssh "$P" /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p &&
sudo apt-get upgrade --dry-run
done < ~/iplist1
```

Result must look like this:

```
Server1 name  
possible updates

Server2 name  
possible updates
```

Comment: There are utilities available to handle automatic updates on ubuntu

Comment: @close voter: How is that not about Ubuntu?

Comment: @Michael This is not about updating but rather getting to know whether there are any updates available. That may seem like nit-picking at first glance, but it is in fact a different thing.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]; do
  ssh "$p" bash -c '\
    hostname &&
    [[ -z "$(/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p)" ]] &&
    echo "No updates available." ||
    ( echo ; apt-get upgrade --dry-run )
    '
  echo
done < ~/iplist1
```

`apt-get --dry-run` doesn't need root permissions to run, this eliminates a major problem.

Comment: yes,look like it's working correct, Thanks You

Comment: yes,but it doesn't run "pt-get upgrade --dry-run" command?

Comment: @AshAdams I tested again and didn't encounter any flaws, it works for me. Of course you can run the subshell with just `hostname && apt-get upgrade --dry-run` instead, if that helps…